# How can I create Map<Integer, List<Object>> with more condition?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have Class like this:

```java
public Sale(...) {
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public Date getField3() {
        return field3;
    }
    public int getField4() {
        return field4;
    }
}
```

I have this list.

```java
List<Sale> exampleList= new ArrayList(); 

a   x    2005    2
a   x    2005    3
b   y    2003    6
b   y    2004    2
c   x    2006    4
c   x    2006    9
```

```java
I want to create a Map<List<Sale>, Integer> with java stream
```

field1   field2   field3  Sum(field4), where the first 3 field is same.

```java
Map<List<Sale>, Integer> target = exampleList.stream().?????
```

Example:

```java
{a   x    2005}    5
{b   y    2003}    6
{b   y    2004}    2
{c   x    2006}    13
```

So how to write a correct stream for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group your list by `field2, field2, field3`. To do so you could override `equals/hashcode` in class `Sale` only for these fields (without `field4`). Then using stream get the result

```
Map<Sale, Integer> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o, Collectors.summingInt(Sale::getField4)));
```